# Where the Camel Application is started?

Tags: java, debugging, apache-camel, intellij-plugin

I have installed [Camel plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/camel-tooling/camel-idea-plugin).

To start debugging, we must create an ad-hoc application

[image]

How do you know exactly at what port application is locally loaded? How can I change it? I have found no configurations about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to provide a port. The debugger is attaching directly to the application using its pid. You need to be sure that the camel-debug dependency is added. I recommened to add it through a profile like shown here https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/d1e5022bb1b43565903359aefaf91bcf23fc9c78/examples/main/pom.xml#L105-L120

Please note that you need a recent version of Camel (3.16 I think)